# IMPORTRANGE row limit?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I have a document where I am trying to mirror some data from one Google sheet to another.  I have over 1000 rows in the first document; when I use the `IMPORTRANGE` formula it works fine as long as the last row in my formula is row 1000.  Any row I add after that in the formula, I get a `#REF` error.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or IMPORTRANGE formula you use?

Answer (score 0):

there is no row limit around the 1000 milestone (for rows). you get the **#REF!** error probably due to some other issue. see this example:

**[spreadsheet A](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RVKzTRTKF7mnkf1LUqIwqSdYooonHBaLYqytgdYQktg/edit#gid=0)** has range `A1:Z2000`

**[spreadsheet B](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jt523OGzWWywaMUQPqFmRmkpSKOe3GQAwHLQLQ2djQM/edit#gid=0)** uses the formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1RVKzTRTKF7mnkf1LUqIwqSdYooonHBaLYqytgdYQktg", "Sheet1!A1:ZZ3000")
```

note the range `A1:ZZ3000`

Answer (score -2):

Seems to be a limit. Working on a 69 column doc with 5906 row entries. I can only populate 5500 rows in the new spreadsheet.
Not sure why...